# how to hide load more button after all data fetch from API?

Tags: reactjs

I have a "Load More" button that I would like to hide when all data has been loaded on the screen. I'm not sure how to handle the state to make the button disappear when all the data is loaded, or if state is what needs to be changed. I have attached my code here. could you please check my code and solve this issues.

My code:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
// import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { Grid, Image, Icon, Segment, Card } from "semantic-ui-react";
class AllOffers extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: [],
      visible: 20,
      isLoading: true,
    };
    this.loadMore = this.loadMore.bind(this);
  }
  loadMore() {
    this.setState((prev) => {
      return { visible: prev.visible + 16 };
    });
  }
  async componentDidMount() {
    const url = "https://localhost:3000/api/v4/web/list";
    const postBody = {
      store_id: 105,
    };

    const requestOptions = {
      method: "POST",
      headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
      body: JSON.stringify(postBody),
    };

    fetch(url, requestOptions)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((json) => {
        this.setState({ data: json.stores });
      })
      .catch((error) => console.error(error))
      .finally(() => {
        this.setState({ isLoading: false });
      });
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.state.data)
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <Grid className="znapoffer">
          <Grid.Column width={16}>
            <p className="znap-all">
              <span>Znap All Offers</span>
            </p>
          </Grid.Column>
        </Grid>
        <Grid columns={4} className="all-offers">
          {this.state.data.slice(0, this.state.visible).map((x, i) => {
            return (
              <Grid.Column key={i}>
                <Segment>
                  <Card>
                    <Link to={x.store_url}>
                      {" "}
                      <Image src={x.image} wrapped ui={false} />
                    </Link>
                    <Card.Content>
                      <Link to={x.store_url}>
                        {" "}
                        <Card.Header>{x.name}</Card.Header>
                      </Link>
                      <Card.Description>{x.store_summary}</Card.Description>
                    </Card.Content>
                    <Card.Content extra>
                      <p className="rewards">
                        <span>
                          <img src="/images/rewards.png" alt=""></img>
                        </span>
                        Cash rewards upto <span>AED {x.cashback}</span>
                      </p>
                      <p className="location">
                        <span>
                          <img src="/images/location.png" alt=""></img>
                        </span>
                        <span className="store-location" key="index">{x.store_branches}</span>
                        {/* {x.store_branches.map((locations, index) => (
                          <span className="store-location" key="index">
                            {index === 0 ? (
                              <span>{locations.store_location}</span>
                            ) : index >= 1 ? (
                              <span>
                                ,&nbsp;&nbsp;{locations.store_location}
                              </span>
                            ) : null}
                          </span>
                        ))} */}
                      </p>{" "}
                    </Card.Content>
                  </Card>
                </Segment>
              </Grid.Column>
            );
          })}
        </Grid>
        <Grid className="znapoffer">
          <Grid.Column width={16}>
            <p className="loading-offers">
              <span
                onClick={this.loadMore}
                className="btn btn-primary load-more"
                Style="cursor:pointer;">
                Loading more offers <Icon name="dropdown" />
              </span>
            </p>
          </Grid.Column>
        </Grid>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}
export default AllOffers;
```

Comment: Could you please solve this issue please.

Answer (score 1):

You can compare the `length` of `visible` and your `data`.

**Length of data > visible => Display Load More**

**Length of data < visible => Do not display Load More**

Like this:

```
{
   (this.state.data||[]).length > this.state.visible && (
      <Grid className="znapoffer">
         <Grid.Column width={16}>
            <p className="loading-offers">
               <span
                  onClick={this.loadMore}
                  className="btn btn-primary load-more"
                  Style="cursor:pointer;">
                  Loading more offers <Icon name="dropdown" />
               </span>
           </p>
         </Grid.Column>
       </Grid>
    )
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment i added above but not working, still loadmore but showing.

Comment: @user5561847 I have made one change in condition. Please check.

Comment: Really awesome, working perfect Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your issue correctly, you can add another `state` variable and set this variable when all items in `data` are shown.
Of course, you can achieve this by not using another variable, but instead checking it like this:

```
{
    !(this.state.visible >= this.state.data?.length) &&
    <Grid className="znapoffer">
    <Grid.Column width={16}>
        <p className="loading-offers">
        <span
            onClick={this.loadMore}
            className="btn btn-primary load-more"
            Style="cursor:pointer;">
            Loading more offers <Icon name="dropdown" />
        </span>
        </p>
    </Grid.Column>
    </Grid>
}
```

This one would be the solution with another `state` variable:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
// import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { Grid, Image, Icon, Segment, Card } from "semantic-ui-react";
class AllOffers extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: [],
      visible: 20,
      isLoading: true,
      allLoaded: false,
    };
    this.loadMore = this.loadMore.bind(this);
  }
  loadMore() {
    this.setState({
        visible: this.state.visible + 16,
        allLoaded: this.state.visible >= this.state.data?.length
    });
  }
  async componentDidMount() {
    const url = "https://localhost:3000/api/v4/web/list";
    const postBody = {
      store_id: 105,
    };

    const requestOptions = {
      method: "POST",
      headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
      body: JSON.stringify(postBody),
    };

    fetch(url, requestOptions)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((json) => {
        this.setState({ data: json.stores });
      })
      .catch((error) => console.error(error))
      .finally(() => {
        this.setState({ isLoading: false });
      });
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.state.data)
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <Grid className="znapoffer">
          <Grid.Column width={16}>
            <p className="znap-all">
              <span>Znap All Offers</span>
            </p>
          </Grid.Column>
        </Grid>
        <Grid columns={4} className="all-offers">
          {this.state.data.slice(0, this.state.visible).map((x, i) => {
            return (
              <Grid.Column key={i}>
                <Segment>
                  <Card>
                    <Link to={x.store_url}>
                      {" "}
                      <Image src={x.image} wrapped ui={false} />
                    </Link>
                    <Card.Content>
                      <Link to={x.store_url}>
                        {" "}
                        <Card.Header>{x.name}</Card.Header>
                      </Link>
                      <Card.Description>{x.store_summary}</Card.Description>
                    </Card.Content>
                    <Card.Content extra>
                      <p className="rewards">
                        <span>
                          <img src="/images/rewards.png" alt=""></img>
                        </span>
                        Cash rewards upto <span>AED {x.cashback}</span>
                      </p>
                      <p className="location">
                        <span>
                          <img src="/images/location.png" alt=""></img>
                        </span>
                        <span className="store-location" key="index">{x.store_branches}</span>
                        {/* {x.store_branches.map((locations, index) => (
                          <span className="store-location" key="index">
                            {index === 0 ? (
                              <span>{locations.store_location}</span>
                            ) : index >= 1 ? (
                              <span>
                                ,&nbsp;&nbsp;{locations.store_location}
                              </span>
                            ) : null}
                          </span>
                        ))} */}
                      </p>{" "}
                    </Card.Content>
                  </Card>
                </Segment>
              </Grid.Column>
            );
          })}
        </Grid>
        {
            !this.state.allLoaded &&
            <Grid className="znapoffer">
            <Grid.Column width={16}>
                <p className="loading-offers">
                <span
                    onClick={this.loadMore}
                    className="btn btn-primary load-more"
                    Style="cursor:pointer;">
                    Loading more offers <Icon name="dropdown" />
                </span>
                </p>
            </Grid.Column>
            </Grid>
        }
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}
export default AllOffers;
```

Answer (score 0):

The identifier needed to decide whether to display load more button or not could either be sent from the backend (when the end of data is reached) or you could set a state value once the data is loaded.

**Example for handling this from backend:**

```
response = {
  ....,
  endOfData: false
}

or

res.setHeader({'endOfData': true});
```

end of data will need to be sent as true if it's the last set of data. You could just send an additional header when the end of data has reached and check for that header to handle loadMore visibility

**Example for handling this in frontend:**

Have an additional state variable for data load completion and its value is set to true when the length has reached.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: [],
      visible: 20,
      isLoading: true,
      dataLoaded: false,
    };
    this.loadMore = this.loadMore.bind(this);
  }

  loadMore() {
    this.setState({
        visible: this.state.visible + 16,
        dataLoaded: this.state.visible >= this.state.data.length
    });
  }

!this.state.dataLoaded && (
  <Grid className="znapoffer">
     <Grid.Column width={16}>
        <p className="loading-offers">
           <span
              onClick={this.loadMore}
              className="btn btn-primary load-more"
              Style="cursor:pointer;">
              Loading more offers <Icon name="dropdown" />
           </span>
       </p>
     </Grid.Column>
   </Grid>
);
```